# Many short groups - a growth model in lmer

Tags: r, mixed-model, growth-model

I'm looking at a test score variable in a longitudinal study of around 10000 children, recorded over three waves (Ages 3,5 and 9). I have every reason to believe that there is substantial variation in both the intercept, and the slope of the Score ~ Age relationship. It would be astonishing if there was not. As expected, the score falls with age, and again, as expected, it falls faster in the earlier years, and more slowly later on. This table illustrates the point.

```
Table: Mean and standard deviation of Score by Age group
```

| Age | Value_mean | Value_sd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 7.793276 | 4.562257 |
| 5 | 7.190196 | 4.755098 |
| 9 | 7.166542 | 5.384476 |

A latent growth curve model (not shown) confirms this.

I'm using lmer to fit a random-intercept, random-slope model. This works fine if I code age as a numeric variable, and does confirm that the random-slopes random-intercept model is reasonable, but if I code Age as I wish to do, as a three level factor variable, the model refuses to fit with the following reasonable message :-

```
lmer5 <- lmer(data=LL, Score ~ Age + (Age|ID))
Error: number of observations (=26804) <= number of random effects (=30450)
for term (Age + 1 | ID); the random-effects parameters and the residual
variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable
```

26804 is the total number of non-missing scores in the data across all three time points.
Not sure where 30450 comes from though?

There are 6,000 or so missing values for Score, so as an experiment, I made a dataset with no missing values for Score, and for this I get the same error message, but the two numbers are the same.

So, I think my call to lmer is correct, though if it's not I would welcome comment, but I can't see an intelligible way of fitting Age, except as a linear effect, which I, and several generations of far more distinguished predecessors, think unlikely to be correct. I think this is a statistical issue, more than an r issue, but I accept it's on the border.

All suggestions welcomed.

Comment: Check that your Age variable is coded as numeric and that you have multiple observations per ID.

Comment: Thanks, It works fine, if Age is coded numeric (3,5,9), but the linear model fits better if it's coded as a factor('3','5','9'), because the true effect is not close to linear in Age. The fall from Age 3 to Age 5, on average, is a lot bigger than the fall form Age 5 to Age 9. This is as expected. The challenge is fitting it!

Comment: If you can't treat age as linear, then you are not estimating a growth curve model. Instead, you probably need to create two 0/1 variables for age in that case. So you have age5 (0/1) and age9 (0/1) that you include in the fixed part of the model, with age3 being the reference category. Then you could introduce age5 and age9 as random slopes. Again, this is no longer a growth model. You are now contrasting the score with age effects at age 5 vs. age 3, and similarly at age 9 vs. age 3.

Comment: Thanks again, I appreciate you input. We could debate what the best name for this model is, for sure some people would agree that growth models imply linear time effects, though others don't. I have fitted exactly the model you suggest, setting Age to be a factor variable, and that's what's giving the error message. I'd prefer to use a linear model, but the substantive evidence is against me, there is a real difference between the Age 3 to Age 5 and the much smaller Age 5 to Age 9 transitions. The issue is understanding a way to reduce the number of parameters being estimated, I think.